# Unchecking a checkbox when clicking on an anchor (CSS only)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to do a sort of drop-down menu for the navbar of an app, in CSS, only.
My navbar, thanks to a checkbox, when checked, expands and when unchecked, hides itself with an animation, what is translated to the user as when he clicks anywhere on the navbar, it hides or expands itself. All the anchors in my navbar are linking to ids.
My problem is that, when I click on any link, the checkbox doesn't uncheck, so the navbar doesn't execute the "draw back" animation.

Here's the navbar what it looks like in html (jade-lang) :

```
 header
      input(type='checkbox')#btn
      label(for='btn')#menu
          nav
              ul
                  li: a(href='#presentation') Accueil
```

And, to give just an idea of what looks like the css :

```
header input {
    display: none;
}

 #menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
    font-weight: 500;
}

header input:checked + #menu {
    -webkit-animation: showMenu 0.5s forwards;
    animation: showMenu 0.5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes showMenu { from { left: 100%; } to { left: 0%; } }
@keyframes showMenu { from { left: 100%; } to { left: 0%; } }

 header input + #menu {
    -webkit-animation: hideMenu 0.5s forwards;
    animation: hideMenu 0.5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hideMenu { from { left: 0%; } to { left: 100%; } }
@keyframes hideMenu { from { left: 0%; } to { left: 100%; } }
```

Simple as that. But I don't get how to have the checkbox unchecking when clicking on any of the links of the navbar.

Thanks :).

**EDIT** I reworded my question.

Comment: Could you make the div a checkbox and styling it to be invisible, and then adding a label and styling that to act in place of the div? That way, you can target the checkbox in your CSS.

Comment: I'm quite sure it's impossible to manipulate the state of form controls using CSS

Comment: @mt_xing Sorry, I reworded my question, because it was faulty, so yeah, I'm already using a checkbox.

Comment: Since you don't want to show that checkbox maybe you could consider using another element, one that can receive focus, like `a` or `button`, and show the menu using `:focus + #menu `: http://jsfiddle.net/nt87koye/

Comment: @pawel Ok, but how do you hide the menu with `a` or `button` after having displayed it ? I think you can't because these two elements are like a toggle, and in CSS, I don't see how it might be possible to make one. A checkbox has litterally 2 states, checked and unchecked, like a lever, a switch, that you manipulate in CSS.

Comment: @iiPLD the menu disappears when the element loses focus, as demonstrated in the linked example above. So clicking anywhere outside of the toggle button will hide the menu.

Comment: @pawel I've just understand ! Thank you so much ! :) If you want, post your answer, I will validate it. Otherwise, I will do it myself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not check/uncheck a checkbox using CSS, you'd need to use some JavaScript. As I understand the point of this excercise is to create a menu toggle type of button in pure CSS.

You can use `:focus + *` instead of `:checked + *`, so you'd need a focusable element, like `<a>`, to toggle the menu:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">Toggle menu</a>
<nav id="menu">
    <a href="#foo">Link</a><br>
    <a href="#bar">Link 2</a>
</nav>
```

** CSS **

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: left 300ms 300ms; /* note the additional transition delay */
}
a:focus + #menu {
    left:0;
    transition-delay:0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nt87koye/2/

This way the menu slides in when the link has focus, and slides out once the focus is lost (user clicks anywhere outside the link).

You could also use the `:target` pseudoclass and place `<a href="#menu">` anywhere on the page, so the feature doesn't rely on specific markup, which is required with the adjacent sibling solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nt87koye/4/